# spring-cloud-stream producer transactionality

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I've done a little testing with the kafka binder and it appears that spring-cloud-stream producers don't participate in spring-managed transactions.

Given code like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public Customer insertCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        customerDao.insertCustomer(customer);
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(CustomerEventHelper.createSaveEvent(customer)).build());
        if (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("rollback test");
        }
        return customer;
    }
```

the customerDao.insertCustomer call is rolled back, but the kafka message was still sent. If I have a consumer on the customer event that inserts the customer into a data warehouse, the data warehouse and system of record will be out of synch on transation rollback. Is there a way to make the kafka binder transactional here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kafka binder is not transactional, and Kafka does not support transactions in general.

We do intend to address transaction management for Spring Cloud Stream 1.1: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/536.

However, you can even currently send messages only after a successful commit by registering a transaction synchronization like this:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
   new TransactionSynchronization(){
       void afterCommit(){                     
           source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(event).build());
    if (true) {

       }
});
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronization.html

Comment: A quick note: because this does not make a  transaction distributed, it is possible that the database update succeeds, but the message sending fails. Therefore it is more common in cases like this to separate the sending of the message from the update by having separate services processing them. E.g.: service A only sends the message, service B receives the message and updates the database. It is generally more straightforward to acknowledge the message only after the transaction succeeded, than to ensure that the message send and database update are an atomic operation.

Comment: I think it's a fine approach for my use case of replicating database changes. I only want the message if the database operation in the system of record succeeded. I'm a bit less concerned about rolling back the system of record operation if the message send failed.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I think I see your point. I'm thinking of using this approach with TransactionSynchronizationManager in cases where I'm adding message production to code that already uses @Transactional.

Comment: You're welcome! It was just meant as a complement to the original comment. Also, I realize that I've described [one form of] event sourcing :), but I'm more concerned with the practical application than with following the pattern rigorously.